# css border not working on mouseover event in chrome?

Tags: html, css

The mouseover function is not working with Google Chrome. Working fine with Firefox and IE. While mouseover the border bottom is not disappearing. But if removing `border-collapse: collapse` it's working fine. Why is this? Any solution.

css:

```
 html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #deecf9;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
}

.border1 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #deecf9;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
}

.border2 {  
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Table:

```
<table width="1024" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td height="9" colspan="4" class="border"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border1" onmouseover="this.className='border2'" onmouseout="this.className='border1'">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="border1" onmouseover="this.className='border2'" onmouseout="this.className='border1'">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="border1" onmouseover="this.className='border2'" onmouseout="this.className='border1'">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="border1" onmouseover="this.className='border2'" onmouseout="this.className='border1'">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you adding `border1:hover { // border 2 class rules; }` ?

Comment: @user1915224 it's working fine for me under Chrome version 23.0 without removing the `border-collapse` property..

Comment: i am using Version 23.0.1271.97 m. Its not working with me!!!

Comment: @user1915224 what do you expect to get and what are you getting?

Comment: FAngel what i am getting is specified in question. I want to get bottom-border 0px on mouseover.

Answer (score 6):

Do it like this: put an transparent border on your normal state elements.
When the :hover is applied the size of the border changes the size the element takes up.

eg:

```
.border1
{   
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-left:1px solid transparent;
    border-right:1px solid transparent;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.border1:hover
{
    border:1px solid transparent;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    padding:1px;
    background-color: #deecf9;
}
```

Your HTML should be something like:

```
<table width="1024" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="table">
<tr>
    <td height="9" colspan="4" class="border"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="border1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="border1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="border1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="border1">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

No need to work with the mouseovers as an attribute, just use css.

Edit: i've noticed that you're using the css `border-collapse` property. This sets whether the table borders are collapsed into a single border or detached as in standard HTML. Try removing this line or set it to "separate", maybe this will work.

Comment: RTB still working only on first <TD> From second <TD> onwards the border bottom is visible onmouseover.

Comment: ATOzTOA yes...but same problem persits.

Comment: yes.... I want to hide border on hover effect. Its not working with chrome. Working fine with Firefox and IE!!!!

Comment: @user1915224 in your question you're trying to hide all borders on hover accept the top border. Is this correct, if you want any else borders you can just edit the css border propety's in my css code.

Comment: Yes...its correct. Only first <TD> showing borderless, the code what are you given. From second <TD> onwards border-bottom is showing...

Comment: Can you post the rest of the css you are using, i'm guessing it's something else here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21375/discussion-between-rtb-and-user1915224)

Comment: If it's not cellpadding and cellspacing or padding or margin then all thaht's left is your border. There is no more.